# Squarespace local development server install gets hung up in middle of installation

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, squarespace, nodist

I have spent hours trying to fix this problem on my own but am getting nowhere and can't seem to see any other questions/solutions regarding my specific problem.

I successfully installed `nodist` via `chocalatey` via `Powershell` admin.

I used the following script in attempting to install the `Squarespace development server` per `Squarespace` documentation:

```
npm install -g @squarespace/server -y
```

Please noted I added the `-y` parameter to for yes to accept license agreement but previously didn't add this parameter but still received same result.

When trying to install the local `Squarespace development server` via `Powershell` admin, the script keeps getting hung up at the following:

> Using this software requires accepting the Squarespace Developer Terms
>   of Use and Oracle Binary Code License Agreement . See LICENSE.txt.

The following is a screenshot of all the scripts that ran beginning from my install script:

[image]

I have done everything from reinstalling `nodist` several times to rebooting machine and everything else to troubleshoot.

Please note that I have also waited for more than an hour to see if the script fully executes but remains hung at the above noted line.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Regards.

Comment: Your issue seems to be that you have not yet clicked an acceptance of the Terms of Use. So you'll need to review the docs of what you're installing from square space and see if there is a place you register yourself as a dev with their platform, then possible click a box to accept their terms of use. From the error you show, that seems to be preventing the install. see https://developers.squarespace.com/local-development

Comment: @JasonAshley Correct, I am registered, I have reviewed the license.txt file, from what i've seen on other forums there should be an option for me to either type 'y' for yes and 'n' for no in PS. There is no option for me to do this.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/benchmarkemail.com/file/d/1b4qIccmdPVaGtrEDQqc0v0Myfbo8z8D4/view?usp=drivesdk . You may want to contact their support or log back in to find that option to accept in your account , see image above

Comment: @JasonAshley hmmm.  I haven't seen this, I'm in the Squarespace account right now via the browser. Where do I nav to accept this as I see no popup and can't locate it from nav bar.

Comment: I'm installing now, based on your install you're adding a '-y' flag, try without it. Docs don't say to do a -y automatically. See image: https://drive.google.com/a/benchmarkemail.com/file/d/10V9doW8DLdMIvuyChMfUbrEIswbCJCrS/view?usp=drivesdk and see docs  https://developers.squarespace.com/get-started

Comment: Also looks like it requires java runtime on your machine, make sure you have jre, check docs for version needed, and add java to your path, here's the image after hitting yes for accepting license https://drive.google.com/a/benchmarkemail.com/file/d/1A43Aw7IaWNberoAKByamuiB26oTgzilj/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @JasonAshley thanks this is helpful. I have tried numerous times previously without the -y param but still had same results.  The -y was a last ditch effort.  Implementing your recommendation of installing JRE.

Comment: everything else looks fine, just check that you have compatible version of java installed and its in your path, see the the squarespace docs where it has the command 'npm start:auth' at https://developers.squarespace.com/get-started  . Good luck, I tried to help.

Comment: @JasonAshley First, thank you for your assistance with this. I've successfully installed JDK v12 and set the environment variables.  Now that I've done this, I'm now getting "npm not recognized" error in PS admin when trying to install Squarespace server

Comment: 1.) I use v8 because of my jenkins install, you might want to check the square space docs if v12 is compatible. 2.)  Did you add something like JAVA_HOME to your System Variables and possibly change your path string? 2a. Do you get a repsonse on the following version queries:  node -v; npm -v; java -version